# Shell script copying all columns of text file instead of specified ones

Tags: shell

I trying to copy 3 columns from one text file and paste them into a new text file. However, whenever I execute this script, all of the columns in the original text file get copied. Here is the code I used:

```
cut -f 1,2,6 PROFILES.1.0.profile > compiledfile.txt
paste compiledfile.txt > myNewFile
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Also, is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the column separator?  Show a small section of sample input and desired output.

Comment: Note that the question as originally posted used `cat` instead of `cut` - I've corrected it to the latter under the assumption that it was a mere typo. However, that leaves one wondering about the purpose of the `paste` command with a single filename operand in the question, because _that_ is essentially the same as `cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use awk to this.

```
awk -F "delimiter" '
{
print $1,$2 ,$3 #Where $1,$2 and so are column numbers
}' filename > newfile
```

Comment: The awk manpage says `-F` remains only for backwards compatibility. I guess it is another way of suggesting to use FS builtin variable. Not very sure though.

Comment: Yes sjsam, -F used as FS here

Comment: @sjsam: Yes, `-F ...` is equivalent to `-v FS=...`. As for the status of `-F`: while it is true that - thanks to the generic `-v ...` option, which was introduced later - there is no strict need for `-F` anymore, `-F` is deeply engrained in `awk` culture and isn't going anywhere, even though the _GNU_ man page vaguely suggests that; by contrast, neither the POSIX spec., nor the man pages for BSD Awk and Mawk qualify `-F` in any way with respect to deprecation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose that the input is comma-separated:

```
$ cat File
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

We can extract columns 1, 2, and 6 using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d, -f 1,2,6 File
1,2,6
a,b,f
```

Note the use of option `-d,` to specify that the column separator is a comma.

By default, `cut` uses a tab as the column separator.  If the separator in your file is anything else, you must use the `-d` option.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk -vFS=your_delimiter_here -vOFS=your_delimiter_here  'print $1,$2,$6' PROFILES.1.0.profile > compiledfile.txt
```

should do it.

For comma separated fields the solution would be

```
awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$2,$6}' PROFILES.1.0.profile > compiledfile.txt
```

`FS` is an `awk builtin` variable which stands for `field-separator`.
Similarly `OFS` stands for `output-field-separator`.

And the handy `-v` option with awk helps you assign a value to variable.